# Textmate Regex Syntax Definition .b Suffix

Tags: regex, assembly, sublimetext2, textmate

Regex is out of my wheelhouse, but I'm still trying to update the existing syntax definition for PIC 18 Assembly (https://github.com/amorrow/pic-assembly-textmate-bundle) to the newer PIC 24/33 instruction set.

I'm basically just extending the keyword list. The issue is that many (but not all) of the instructions have byte variants, eg, the `mov` instruction has a `mov.b` variant. The highlighting works for the `mov` portion of the instruction, but omits highlighting the `.b`. Adding `mov` as well as `mov.b` to the keyword list didn't work, and neither did adding `mov\.b`.

Here's what it looks like (instruction list abbreviated for readability):

```
    <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>\b(add|addc|mov)\b</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>keyword.mnemonic</string>
    </dict>
```

Regex is still very alien to me, and I'm unsure how to let it know that `mov.b` is one entire instruction.

Comment: Regex patterns are obviously read from left to right. If you want to add `mov\.b` in a list that contains `mov`, you must place it before `mov` in the list. An other way consists to use the quantifiers greediness, replacing `mov` by `mov(?:\.b)?`

Comment: I just added each variant before the base instruction. Not the most elegant solution, but it works well enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the prefixed instructions before the base instruction in the list fixed the issue.

Eg:

```
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>\b(add\.b|add|addc\.b|addc|mov\.b|mov)\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>keyword.mnemonic</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: I would just mention that a regex doing the same thing, but shorter (and likely more efficient) would be `\b((?:addc?|mov)(?:\.b)?)\b`. Of course, it's still up to you if you want to use that or keep yours.

Answer (score 0):

What about `\b(?:add|addc|mov)(?:\.\S+)?\b`? Works for things like "mov.b", "mov.b.cde", etc.

I added an optional "." followed by one or more non-whitespace characters.

Comment: The issue here is that not all instructions have `.b` (or `.c` or `.z`) variants.

Comment: Did you not try the regex? I even explained that `\.\S+` is optional, so things like "mov" and "add" match too.

Comment: As I said, I really don't get regex, nor did I really understand your explanation - the code is largely gibberish to me. The list of instructions is rather large - would I have separate lists for those that do allow different suffixes?

Comment: Is it always either the base keyword or some keywords optionally followed by a ".b"? Or could ".b" be anything like ".asdf"? You need to describe what you're trying to match better.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggest it in my comment you can use a non-capturing group `(?:...)` and the quantifier `?` to reduce the regex engine work:

```
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>\b(add(?:\.b)?|addc(?:\.b)?|mov(?:\.b)?)\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>keyword.mnemonic</string>
</dict>
```

or with more factorization: *(I added the `nop` and `rlf` mnemonics to show the level depth of parenthesis)*

```
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>\b(nop|(?:addc?|mov)(?:\.b)?|rlf)\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>keyword.mnemonic</string>
</dict>
```